# Convex Set and an interior point

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, convex-analysis

Given a bounded convex set in $R^2$ with atleast 3 non-collinear points, can we find a point in $R^2$ such that any line passing through it cuts boundary atleast or exactly two points.

Can we prove it logically, I know that any point in triangle formed by 3 non-collinear points should work.

Comment: Any point inside the convex set works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **NO**.

For example, the convex set $S= \mathbb R^2$ doesn't have this property.

A non-trivial counterexample is the region below the graph of your favourite concave down function. A vertical line will only meet the boundary once.

One another hand, if your question is

**Question:** Given a **bounded** convex set in R2 with at least 3 non-collinear points, can we find a point in R2 such that any line passing through it cuts boundary atleast or exactly two points.

The answer is yes. Note that any such set contains a triangle and hence a disk.

We will prove the following stronger statement.

**Lemma** If $A \subset \mathbb R^2$ is a bounded set which contains a disk, then any line through any point in this disk will meet the boundary at least twice.

Proof: Fix an arbitrary point $\alpha$ strictly inside. Draw an arbitrary ray from $\alpha$ in any direction. A small interval at the beginning is inside $A$, and towards infinity the ray gets outside $A$ (because $A$ is **bounded**).

A standard argument show that there is at least a boundary point in between [let me know if you need the details], and this point is not $\alpha$

Now, if we pick any line through $\alpha$, it is made of two such rays in opposite direction. Each of the rays contains a point, which is not $\alpha$, which is on the boundary, and those two points are distinct (since $\alpha$ is the only common point on the two rays).

Comment: @Sushil Then, the second part is the proof. If you meet these notions before, what the lemma says is that "Every bounded set with non-empty interior has the property you want". The condition you give imply non-empty interior.

Comment: If x is an interior point of a bounded convex set  $A$ then every line through x meets the boundary at exactly two points. Equivalently, every ray (half-line) through it meets the boundary at exactly one point. To prove this you have to take any unit vector u and consider the supremum of all $r>0$ such that $x+rx \in A$. Call this supremum $\rho$.Then show that $x+\rho u $ belongs to the boundary of A. For $r>\rho$ we can show that $x+ru$ is in the exterior of A and for $0<r<\rho$ $x_ru$ is in the interior of A.

Comment: A ray is homeomorphic image of $[0,\infty)$, now points on ray lying in convex set form a connected set, hence inverse image should be a connected set only. It can't be $[0,\infty)$ because then its image which is the ray must be in A but ray is unbounded while A is not. Hence inverse image is $[0, x]$. And now claim is that image of $x$ is boundary point of $A$. Obviously it is not in exterior because then it will have some ball around it outside being exterior of clouser open and we will get contradiction to definition of $x$.

Comment: hence if not on boundary then it is in interior. Then there will a ball around it which will contain image of an interval around $x$, which will then contradict definition of $x$. And $x>0$, because there is already a ball in interior.

Comment: and it also shows that there are exactly two points.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^2$ be a convex set with at least 3 non-collinear points $A,B,C \in S$. That means $\Delta ABC \subset S$, since $S$ is convex and hence contains the convex hull of any subset.

Let $M$ be the center of mass of $\Delta ABC$, then $M$ is an interior point of $\Delta ABC$. Hence, $\exists r > 0$ such that the open ball $\mathcal{B} = B(M,r) \subsetneq \Delta ABC \subset S$.

Note that since $M$ is an interior point of $\mathcal{B}, S$ and $\Delta ABC$, any line through $M$ is a diameter of $\mathcal{B}$, hence it will cut the boundary of $\mathcal{B}$ in exactly 2 places.

Can you finish this?

Comment: What if $S= \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @N.S. i thought OP wants bounded sets, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not bounded